# confusing usages of the word "except"

Tags: difference

Here are two use cases of "except" that are confusing to me and found in LONGMAN dictionary.

> 1. She had nothing to do except spend money. (given for the usage *except do something*)
> 2. He wouldn’t talk about work, except to say that he was busy. (given for the usage *except to do something*)

Are both usages equivalent? Can I paraphrase the first sentence into "She had nothing to do except to spend money."? and also can I paraphrase the second sentence into "He wouldn’t talk about work, except say that he was busy."?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. The first uses a bare infinitive, the second a **to** infinitive. The first means **apart from spending money**, the second **apart from saying**. (The answer to your question is yes, **except say** is the bare infinitive form of **except to say**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first substitution, you add "to":

> She had nothing to do except [to] spend money.

The bare infinitive is normally used after "except":
[Oxford Guide to English Grammar](https://books.google.com/books?id=NrpZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22After%20except%20and%20but%20(%3D%20except)%20we%20normally%20use%20a%20bare%20infinitive.%22&dq=%22After%20except%20and%20but%20(%3D%20except)%20we%20normally%20use%20a%20bare%20infinitive.%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjh55Pt_qrtAhVEtTEKHbg6DmYQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg)

> **a** After except and but (= except) we normally use a bare infinitive.
> *As for the housework, I do everything except cook.*

On the other hand, with the added "to", it doesn't sound wrong to me.

However, in the second example, I don't think the "to" can be left out. It's a to-infinitive that starts a purpose clause:

> He wouldn't talk about work except to say that he was busy.

That sentence is a way of saying

> He **talked** about work **to say** that he was busy.

This sounds wrong to me:
*He talked about work say he was busy.

And this also sounds wrong to me:
*He wouldn't talk about work except say he was busy.